# Erro ao ler um número long em java

Tags: java

Estou ler um vetor em java e fazer o somatório de todos os elemento porém esta falando que são tipo incompatíveis, como resolver

Meu código

```
package capitulo2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Capitulo2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    long i, tam,soma=0;
    tam = teclado.nextLong();
    long [] vetor = new long[10000002];
    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        vetor[i] = teclado.nextLong();
        soma += vetor[i];
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: em que momento da o erro?

Comment: o próprio netbeans imite uma alerta

Comment: Por que nao soma direto? Precisa armazenar em vetor mesmo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os arrays devem ser indexados com `int`, não podem ser com `long`. Faça a variável `i` ser `int` e esse problema de compilação estará solucionado. O melhor lugar para declarar a variável `i` é no próprio laço `for`. Por exemplo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Capitulo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        long soma = 0;
        long tam = teclado.nextLong();
        long[] vetor = new long[10000002];
        for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
            vetor[i] = teclado.nextLong();
            soma += vetor[i];
        }
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/vYKJp2)

Comment: Obrigado Victor

Comment: @rafaelmarques , se resolveu seu problema, não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita clicando no ✅. Eu, por exemplo, não sabia da questão de que não posso indexar por `long`, pensava que fazia `cast` automático, então ela me foi bastante útil. E olha que já são 5 anos mexendo profissionalmente com Java e eu ignorava este fato

Comment: @Jefferson Quesado, pronto marquei, é vivendo e aprendendo